# Parsing forex JSON with Java

Tags: java, json, forex

Okay, so I'm trying to run a very basic java script to retrieve Forex quotes to then work with.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class forex {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL oanda = new URL("http://api-sandbox.oanda.com/v1/prices?instruments=EUR_USD");
        URLConnection yc = oanda.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

When I execute the script, I get the following:

```
{
    "prices" : [
        {
            "instrument" : "EUR_USD",
            "time" : "2014-05-18T13:47:57.376221Z",
            "bid" : 1.25482,
            "ask" : 1.25491
        }
    ]
}
```

What I can't work out **AT ALL** is how to parse the result into usable variables to work with from there on?

Any help much appreciated!!

Comment: You get a Map back from parsing the JSON.  The "prices" element of he Map contains a List of additional Maps, one for each quote.  Just peel it like an onion, one layer at a time.  (But of course you need to use a JSON parser first -- there are dozens to choose from.  Just don't start with Jackson or you'll never figure out what you're doing.)

Comment: Thanks! I'm giving it a go now...will let you know how I get on!

Comment: It is not a java script, it is java, is not it ?

Comment: Sorry, yes it's a java script, as opposed to a JavaScript

Comment: api-sandbox.oanda.com ? Isn't the sandbox environment dead for over a year ? You also use the v1 REST-API. That one is announced to be deprecated in May 2018. So, if it still works, it probably isn't for long. You should make use of the V20 REST interface. It offers more functionality too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use Java, why not use the Dukascopy Jforex platform?
I believe you'll do your job quicker. You can directly pull data from your Java platform to your application.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Jackson and then create a POJO class called Prices. Prices will have the instrument, time, bid, and ask as instance variables, as well as getters/setters.

Using Jackson you can then map the parsed JSON to your Prices object and use getters to retrieve values. It makes it very simple.

Maven Dependency: 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core

Your main method would look something like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;

public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

try {

  //create object mapper
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  //read JSON file and convert to POJO

  Prices prices = mapper.readValue(new File("data/sample.json"), Prices.class);

  //print info

  System.out.println("Instrument: " + prices.getInstrument());
  System.out.println("Time: " + prices.getTime());
  System.out.println("Bid: " + prices.getBid()); 
  Sytem.out.println("Ask: " + prices.getAsk()); 



}

catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
 }
}
```